# Split ViewPager Loading

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using `ViewPager` from [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/ViewPagerExampleActivity.java) to load images to my app:

```
static class TouchImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private static int[] images = { R.drawable.nature_1, R.drawable.nature_2, R.drawable.nature_3, R.drawable.nature_4, R.drawable.nature_5 };

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return images.length;
        }

        @Override
        public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            TouchImageView img = new TouchImageView(container.getContext());
            img.setImageResource(images[position]);
            container.addView(img, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            return img;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == object;
        }
```

However, I need to load 12 images. As a result, I got `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 18633612 byte allocation with 16308864 free bytes and 15MB until OOM` error suspected due to loading of 12 images.

My question is, is it possible to split the `ViewPager` loading. During `onCreat`, I just load 3 of my images. As the user slides through the `Pager`, it will load addition 2 of subsequence images. Is it possible?

Comment: Even if you load 3 images initially & adding 2 from there after, still you will reach to the point of OutOfMemoryError. So load them using an Image loading library.

Comment: What if I add 2 new and delete 2 previous?